# Are variable declarations and branching and looping control constructs only used in procedures?

Tags: sql, sql-psm

In SQL/PSM, are variable declarations and branching and looping control constructs only used in procedures and functions? Can they be used outside procedures and functions? Thanks.

Comment: According to ANSI SQL, yes.

Comment: Thanks. Could you link me to where it is mentioned?

Comment: Example here: http://developer.mimer.se/documentation/html_101/Mimer_SQL_Engine_DocSet/SQL_Statements19.html